# Why is there no O_SEARCH flag under Linux for open function?

Tags: linux, unix

Let's say I need to get the file descriptor of a file (or a directory) which has only execution (or search) permission.

The X/Open norm defines a O_SEARCH flag for the open() function. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html

However, Linux doesn't. There are only 3 available flags (O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY and O_RDWR). See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html

Why? And how can I get the fd of a directory with only search permission?

Thanks

Comment: good question.  Is there a problem with just opening a directory for reading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out Linux doesn't support, yet, this flag, as stated in W. Richard Stevens Stephen A. Rago's book "Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment" which you can have a look at here [Link to the book on google books](https://books.google.fr/books?id=kCTMFpEcIOwC&pg=PA63&lpg=PA63&dq=support%20O_SEARCH%20flag%20open&source=bl&ots=zvMAXR-uqK&sig=1HghJfNNFZTjpD1ySFDwSPax96k&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwif8O7RyYrUAhVmJsAKHb2ECtoQ6AEISjAF#v=onepage&q=support%20O_SEARCH%20flag%20open&f=false)

Actually, the flag is defined in POSIX, implemented in standard C library (which is in this case glibc, that's why you find it under man 3 open) but is not implemented in Linux kernel (thus not found under man 2 open).

EDIT 1 : 
Since we use GNU under Linux, it includes specific headers for Linux to be able to make appropriate system calls that are feasable by Linux (in this case, it includes fcntl-linux.h in addition to fcntl.h).

EDIT 2 : Bug ticket
https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18228

Please, correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: Glibc doesn't even define the macro at all.

Comment: This triggers me so much. Glibc claims it is compliant with POSIX.1, although POSIX.1 clearly defines O_SEARCH flag and glibc doesn't...

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, you can obtain an fd for a directory that only has search permission using `O_PATH`. On other POSIX systems, you can fork a process and `chdir` to the directory; whenever you want to do `openat` relative to that directory, you can have the process perform `open` for you and send the fd to your main process (`AF_UNIX` and `SCM_RIGHTS` are a portable way of doing this).

Neither is strictly equivalent to `O_SEARCH` in the case where search permissions are revoked from the directory before access. POSIX guarantees that there will be no further permissions checks for an fd opened with `O_SEARCH`, but both `O_PATH` and `chdir` will check on every access.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `open(3)` (it looks like 3P in man pages, [link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/open.3p.html)) you should see that flag. I use ArchLinux updated at 2017-05-24.

EDIT 1: I edit the post to put a [link to the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8EIy.png) so you can see the image, althoug I cannot use it in C.

If you want to look for into a directory, use `opendir`, `readdir` and the syscalls used for directory managing.

---

> Why? And how can I get the fd of a directory with only search permission?

I don't know if that helps, but you can open read-only and look for the file you need, and then open that file with `fopen` in read-only mode.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The page you linked if of the POSIX norm. The linux I'm using (Ubuntu 16.04) doesn't seem to have the O_SEARCH flag.

Are you sure ArchLinux has this flag?

Comment: Yeah, I did a `man 3 open` and it showed me that. The page I linked it's the man page's project from kernel.org ([see it](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/)). Go to "3: Library functions" and look for `open(3p)`.

Comment: That's the thing. The flag is available for the C-library function, but is absent for the system function. Anyway, thank you for your help!